# Determining navigation type from PerformanceNavigationTiming

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I used to determine if user had come by clicking the back button in the previous page using `window.performance.navigation.type` like

```
if (window.performance.navigation.type === 2) {
    window.location.reload()
}
```

I saw that this property has been deprecated and succeeded by [Navigation Timing Level 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming). How can I mimic the behavior of performance.navigation api by this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I should preface this by saying that I am not JavaScript pro. This is my approach for utilizing [Navigation Timing Level 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming).

```
if (String(window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type) === "back_forward") {
    window.location.reload()
}
```

`window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")` returns a list of PerformanceEntry objects every [mark](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByType) set. If you haven't set any marks, this list contains a single object that has the navigation information for the window.

Comment: Is there any constant to check if it is "back_forward"? Is it a good idea to check with a hardcoded string directly. I saw that there are constants in PerformanceNavigation like PerformanceNavigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD, but I couldn't find anything for strings or a map of integer codes vs strings.

Answer (score 5):

window.performance.**navigation.type** is **deprecated**.

Here is my solution for **Typescript and Angular** (place this in `app.component.ts` on your `ngOnInit()` hook

```
if((window.performance.getEntries()[0] as PerformanceNavigationTiming).type  === 'reload'){
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
}
```