# Vue 3 Go home on refresh

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have a vuetify (vue 3) app. When I (hard) refresh my web app, I'd like to be redirected to my very first route (for isntance, Skills). Instead I go to the last route I was on.

Here are my routes.

```
const routes = [
  { 
    path: '/', 
    name: "Skills",
    component: Skills,
    beforeEnter: checkIfAuthenticated,
  },
  { 
    path: '/myskills', 
    name: "MySkills",
    component: MySkills,
    beforeEnter: checkIfAuthenticated,
  },
  { 
    path: '/history', 
    name: "History",
    component: History,
    beforeEnter: checkIfAuthenticated,
  },
  { 
    path: '/conversations', 
    name: "Conversations",
    component: Conversations,
    beforeEnter: checkIfAuthenticated,
  },
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    name: "PageNotFound",
    component: PageNotFound,
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
})
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible.  Given a URL, a browser is going to load that URL.  Unless you have a permanent redirect, nothing can be done to tell it to "actually, load this other page instead"

Comment: By the way, you can redirect on refresh & hard refresh. But you can't only do it with a hard refresh. Because you can't simply detect only hard refresh [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54040182/detect-a-hard-reload-with-javascript). If you need and for both refresh and hard refresh I can answer.

Comment: Thanks nur_riyad, I don't care about the type of refresh. Where would you detect page reload in vuejs (I'm new to it)? Thanks

Comment: According to MDN you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type as demonstrated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54244573/5962802

Comment: Thanks IVO. I was wondering if there was a Vue specific way of doing it. But I'll try to figure it out. Thanks!